# Detect if key was pressed once

Tags: python, winapi

I wanted to do an action, as soon as my <kbd>f</kbd> key is pressed. The problem is that it spams the action.

```
import win32api

while True:
    f_keystate = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x46)

    if f_keystate < 0:
        print("Pressed!")
```

I would like this without "Pressed!" being spammed but only printed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the `while` loop, when the <kbd>f</kbd> key is pressed, `GetAsyncKeyState` will detect that the <kbd>f</kbd> key is always in the pressed state. As a result, the `print` statement is called repeatedly.

Try the following code, you will get the result you want:

```
import win32api

while True:
    keystate = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x46)&0x0001
    if keystate > 0:
       print('F pressed!')
```

Comment: @user13591244 If the answer useful to you, please mark it to end the thread. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need a state variable that will keep track of whether the key has been pressed after it's been released.

```
f_pressed = False

while not f_pressed:
    f_pressed = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x46) < 0

print("Pressed!")
```

Comment: It works! But how can I make it not stop the program without putting it into a while loop? Is there a way?

Comment: There's nothing that says that you need to stop the program, but printing "Pressed" was all your original code did (and you said you only wanted to do it once), so that's all this does.  :)  If there's other stuff your program needs to do, you'll need to integrate this code into it in such a way that the program still does the other stuff.

Comment: I will try it. I want to implement it into a GUI. If it works, I'll let you know. Thanks though :)

Comment: You might want to check whether the GUI framework you're using provides any helpful APIs to send you an event when a key is pressed, rather than requiring you to poll the keyboard directly in a loop.  It'll save you a *lot* of hassle if you don't have to implement that low-level I/O logic yourself!

Comment: You should also try putting a sleep in your loop

Comment: *"You need a state variable"* - No, you don't. You only need to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm super late, but I ran across the same problem myself when using the keyboard module. Here's the solution I found, and yes, it is asynchronous.

```
    if keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
        if checksPressed == 0:
            # run code
        checksPressed += 1
    else:
        checksPressed = 0
```

or for win32api

```
if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x46) < 0:
        if checksPressed == 0:
            # run code
        checksPressed += 1
    else:
        checksPressed = 0
```